# Different PDCheckBox Appearances on Mac Preview and Adobe Acrobat when using PDFBox

Tags: java, jruby, pdfbox

I am trying to add a margin to a PDCheckBox field. I am able to do this successfully using PDFBox. However, when I view the PDF on **Mac Preview** and on **Adobe Acrobat Reader**, I see two slightly different checkboxes.

Checkbox on Mac Preview:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0agP.jpg

Checkbox on Adobe Acrobat Reader:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HytI5.jpg

I need them to look exactly the same on either pdf reader.

Here is a pseudocode example of how I am creating that **margin effect** with PDFBox.

**Note:** I excluded some code for creating the checkbox (like setting up the border styles, setting the name, etc.) since I used the [library's checkbox creation example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java?view=markup). The border color is black, the background color is white, and there is a `lineWidth` of 1.

```rb
widgetBoundingBox = PDRectangle.new(200, 400, 50, 50)

margin = 10

widgetBoundingBoxWithMargin = PDRectangle.new(
  200 - margin,
  400 - margin,
  widgetBoundingBox.getWidth + margin * 2,
  widgetBoundingBox.getHeight + margin * 2
)

pdCheckBox = PDCheckBox.new(pdAcroForm)
pdAnnotationWidget = pdCheckBox.getWidgets[0]

# This replaces lines 73 of the example
pdAnnotationWidget.setRectangle(widgetBoundingBoxWithMargin)

...

# This replaces lines 112 - 113 of the example
checkboxAppearanceStream = PDAppearanceStream.new(pdDocument)
checkboxAppearanceStream.setBbox(
  PDRectangle.new(
    widgetBoundingBoxWithMargin.getWidth,
    widgetBoundingBoxWithMargin.getHeight
  )
)

...

# Adding a large white box that takes up the width and height
# of the checkbox including margins
# this will get placed as a background behind the checkbox
# This replaces lines 121 - 123 of the example
checkboxContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(backgroundColor)
checkboxContentStream.addRect(
  0.0,
  0.0,
  widgetBoundingBoxWithMargin.getWidth,
  widgetBoundingBoxWithMargin.getHeight
)
checkboxContentStream.fill

# Adding the checkbox
# This gets overlaid on top of the previous rectangle
# and offset by the margin that we want
# This replaces lines 124 - 126 of the example
checkboxContentStream.setStrokingColor(borderColor)
checkboxContentStream.addRect(
  (lineWidth / 2.0) + margin,
  (lineWidth / 2.0) + margin,
  width - lineWidth,
  height - lineWidth
)
checkboxContentStream.stroke
```

Comment: Please share the PDF, it is difficult to read the code... seems that the BBox is larger than the rectangle of the widget...

Comment: Please be aware that pdf viewers to a certain degree are free to recreate appearances of annotations. Thus, your attempt to make them *look exactly the same on either pdf reader* may be doomed from the start.

Comment: Here is a link to the PDF: http://www.filedropper.com/weird-checkbox

Comment: /NeedAppearances is set to true (you likely used an existing file). This means that the viewer should recreate the appearance.